# Hide admin folder from url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, admin, administrator

**Current URL**

```
http://www.example.com/admin/data/img/gallery/myimages.jpg
http://www.example.com/admin/data/content/mycontents.html
```

So

**Current SCRIPTS / HTMLS / FILES OF WEBPAGE CONTAIN and shows in browser source code**

```
<img src="/admin/data/img/gallery/myimage.jpg">
<?php include("/admin/data/content/mycontents.html"); ?>
```

This is "CMS system" in a folder named "admin"

What i want to do is Hide the admin folder from every script /php/html output to browser.
So no body can see or search engines can't capture this area (Security concern)
So when the browser output the content or script it will rewrite the above urls to this

**Removing the admin**

```
 http://www.example.com/data/img/gallery/myimages.jpg
    http://www.example.com/data/content/mycontents.html
```

Inside browser source code

```
<img src="/data/img/gallery/myimage.jpg">
```

or
**removing the data too**

```
http://www.example.com/img/gallery/myimages.jpg
http://www.example.com/content/mycontents.html
```

Kindly help also it must work for www.example.com as well as example.com

Solution through htaccess and mod_rewrite
i do not have access to httpd.conf
Also i do not want to move the folder a lots of scripts are there in the folder so have to write a lot.
Also tell me where should i place it in the root or in the admin folder

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this to the .htaccess file in your document root (where the "admin" folder is in):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/admin/data/%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/admin/data/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/data/$1 [L]
```

The conditions check that if the request URI gets prepended with "/admin/data/", if it points to an existing file or directory. If it does, then rewrite the URI so that there's an "/admin/data/" in front of the request. If you don't want to be able to map directories into /admin/data, then remove the second condition (the one with `-d`) and remove the `[OR]` flag from the first.

Comment: it doesn't work..I place the .htaccess in the root folder than the website didn't work www.example.com i have to put the index.php. than also it was not working the URL is same can u help